# Where should JSON-LD be placed on my website?

Tags: json-ld

Where do I add the following JSON-LD to my website?

```
{ "@context": "http://schema.org", "@type": "Organization", "url": "http://www.seekersweb.com/p/anna-university-results-and-student.html", "logo": "http://www.seekersweb.com/2018/08/anna-university-internal-marks.html" }
```

Answer (score 1):

You just add it to a `<script type="application/ld+json">` tag in the bottom of your `<body>` tag.
With your example, it will look like this;

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{ "@context": "http://schema.org", "@type": "Organization", "url": "http://www.seekersweb.com/p/anna-university-results-and-student.html", "logo": "http://www.seekersweb.com/2018/08/anna-university-internal-marks.html" }
</script>
```